# Spinejs. Has no method 'hasMany'

Tags: javascript, spine.js

I have problem with spinejs associations.

```
  class Category extends Spine.Model
    @configure 'Category', 'name', 'id'
    @extend Spine.Model.Ajax

    @hasMany 'children_categories', 'Category'
    @url: Route.categories()
```

but it writes an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object Category(name, id) has no method 'hasMany'

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the `relation.js` file? Per the [documentation](http://spinejs.com/docs/relations):

> Spine's relationship logic is available in a separate module to the
>   rest of the library, relation.js. You'll need to include that in your
>   application before continuing.